# How do you link a custom object to docusign created through Conga Composer

Tags: docusign, conga

I am having all sorts of fun with Conga Composer and Docusign in Salesforce.  I have a template populating fine and a docusign document being delivered perfectly.  The one last piece I am trying to work out is populating the reference to the custom object on the Docusign Status.  Everything I have read says that this should populate by padding the &Id in the button.  The following is my button specification.

```
https://composer.congamerge.com?SolMgr=1
&sessionId={!API.Session_ID}
&serverUrl={!API.Partner_Server_URL_290}
&Id={!Application__c.Id}

&QueryId=[ApplicationDetails]a1G280000007h3P?pv0={!Application__c.Id},
[InvoiceDetails]a1G280000007h3U?pv0={!Application__c.Id}

&TemplateId=a1t28000000EhLc

&UF0=1
&MFTS0=Application_Status__c
&MFTSValue0=Offer+Sent

&DocuSignVisible=1
&DocuSignR1Id={!Application__c.Applicant_Id__c}
&DocuSignR1Type=Signer
&DocuSignR1Role=Signer+1
```

The docusign status record gets created, but the application lookup that I added to it is not populated.  I have also done the configuration in the docusign side to point the Application Id on the document status to the External Envelope Id.

Has anyone come across this before?

Answer (score 0):

You've also got to create the lookup and map back via Connect in DocuSign. Instructions can be found [here](https://support.docusign.com/guides/dfs-admin-guide-add-ds-status-to-custom-object).